# How do I implement a depth first search algorithm for a directed graph using an adjacency list in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, iterator, depth-first-search

I need help writing a method that returns an iterator over all nodes in a graph, according to the order they are encountered in a DFS traversal.  The method needs to use a stack and not be recursive.

```
Iterator<T> dfsNodeListing(T start){
    //Where start is the node that the dfs traversal will begin from.
}
```

I have successor and predecessor set in the form of Hashtables to keep track of the edges going to and from each node.  I also have an ArrayList that a node gets added to if it is visited by the search.

```
private Hashtable <T, Set<T>> pred = new Hashtable<>();
private Hashtable <T, Set<T>> succ = new Hashtable<>();
private ArrayList<T> mark = new ArrayList <>();
```

How can all of these elements be brought together?

EDIT: This is what I am currently working with.  I get caught up somewhere in the middle and the method never completes.

```
public Iterator<T> dfsNodeListing(T start) {
    Stack<T> stk = new Stack<>();
    stk.push(start);
    if(!mark.contains(start)){
        mark.add(start);
        stk.push(start);
        while(!stk.isEmpty()){
            stk.pop();
            for(T n : succ.get(start)){
                if(!mark.contains(n)){
                    stk.push(n);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return mark.iterator();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you've tried so far? Or provide a recursive solution and ask for help in making it non-recursive?

Comment: As a side note, `HashTable` is a synchronized class.  Typically we use `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `foreach` loop has a problem because you only get successors of `start` node instead of the node that you popped from the stack. You can modify your code like:

```
while(!stk.isEmpty()){
        for(T n : succ.get(stk.pop())){
        if(!mark.contains(n)){
            stk.push(n);
            mark.add(n);
        }
    }
}
```